# RestTemplate exchange gets wrong response after I upgrade to spring framework 2

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, resttemplate

I have a token restful service, which generates the following info when I use postman to hit it (GET).

```
{
"authorities": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "authority": "admin"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "authority": "ROLE_USER"
    }
],
"details": {
    "remoteAddress": "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1",
    "sessionId": null,
    "tokenValue": "7760e769-9b1e-4669-8b6d-85e51809934d",
    "tokenType": "bearer",
    "decodedDetails": null
},
"authenticated": true,
"userAuthentication": {
    "authorities": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "authority": "admin"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "authority": "ROLE_USER"
        }
    ],
    "details": {
        "remoteAddress": "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1",
        "sessionId": null
    },
    "authenticated": true,
    "principal": {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "sysadmin",
        "password": "$2a$10$xm6.EOh8GrsnwRy91d2cueZPwvPojuExnYEGy1auFyzqYTtdlHvUe",
        "accountNonExpired": true,
        "accountNonLocked": true,
        "credentialsNonExpired": true,
        "enabled": true,
        "authorities": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "authority": "admin"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "authority": "ROLE_USER"
            }
        ],
        "userId": "1"
    },
    "credentials": null,
    "name": "sysadmin"
},
"credentials": "",
"oauth2Request": {
    "clientId": "movez",
    "scope": [
        "all"
    ],
    "requestParameters": {
        "grant_type": "refresh_token"
    },
    "resourceIds": [],
    "authorities": [],
    "approved": true,
    "refresh": false,
    "redirectUri": null,
    "responseTypes": [],
    "extensions": {},
    "grantType": "refresh_token",
    "refreshTokenRequest": null
},
"principal": {
    "id": 1,
    "username": "sysadmin",
    "password": "$2a$10$xm6.EOh8GrsnwRy91d2cueZPwvPojuExnYEGy1auFyzqYTtdlHvUe",
    "accountNonExpired": true,
    "accountNonLocked": true,
    "credentialsNonExpired": true,
    "enabled": true,
    "authorities": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "authority": "admin"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "authority": "ROLE_USER"
        }
    ],
    "userId": "1"
},
"clientOnly": false,
"name": "sysadmin"
}
```

However, when I use RestTemplate exchange to make the api call, I get the following,
[image]

The problem here is

1. There are two layers "authorities", which doesn't match the structure in the Json.
2. If we go deep, we only have the authority "ROLE_USER", the "admin" is not retrieved.

My code is

```
Map auth = restTemplate.exchange(tokenVerifyUri, HttpMethod.GET, entity, Map.class).getBody();
```

It previously worked fine but have this trouble after I upgrade spring to 2.0 (not sure if it is related).

Please help. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

If I change Map.class to String.class in exchange function, I got the correct Json.

Comment: In your code, can you print out the Map you get back as a JSON string?  It will be easier to compare to the Postman JSON.

Comment: @JoseMartinez, when I use Gson to convert it to JSON String, it is reflect the map I got, which means it is diff from the JSON I got from postman

Comment: How do you map the thing? you ask for a hashmap of hashmap ? which explain why you have only 1 item in a map as the list cannot fit in the map model. Why not creating real bean with correct schema so that data fit in it?